# Maintaining HTTP session when accessing a servlet from Android

Tags: java, android, servlets

I am not able to maintain session when I access a servlet from Android. I just pass the parametres along with the URL to the servlet which gathers data from database and stores it in the session, but I am not able to retrieve it on subsequent requests.

Does the session get expired when I close the `PrintWriter` in the servlet?

Answer (score 4):

This is a problem in the client side. The HTTP session is maintained by a cookie. The client needs to ensure that it properly sends the cookie back on the subsequent requests as per the HTTP spec. The HttpClient API offers the [`CookieStore`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/CookieStore.html) class for this which you need to set in the [`HttpContext`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/protocol/HttpContext.html) which you in turn need to pass on every [`HttpClient#execute()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html#execute%28org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest,%20org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext%29) call.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
HttpContext httpContext = new BasicHttpContext();
httpContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
// ...

HttpResponse response1 = httpClient.execute(yourMethod1, httpContext);
// ...

HttpResponse response2 = httpClient.execute(yourMethod2, httpContext);
// ...
```

To learn more about how sessions works, read this answer: [How do servlets work? Instantiation, sessions, shared variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/java-servlet-instantiation-and-session-variables/3106909#3106909)