# Spring MVC + Spring Security - Controller Authentication using JSON

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'd like to use simple Spring controller to authenticate the Users using Spring Security.

My Controller

```
@Controller
@Scope("request")
public class Authenticator {

private String username;
private String password;

@Autowired
private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = {RequestMethod.POST })
public @ResponseBody String authentication(@RequestParam("login") String userName,
        @RequestParam("password") String password, HttpServletRequest request) {

    this.username = userName;
    this.password = password;

    Authentication authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
            userName, password);
    try {

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager
                .authenticate(authenticationToken);


        SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder
                .getContext();

        securityContext.setAuthentication(authentication);

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        session.setAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT", securityContext);

        return "sucess";
    } catch (AuthenticationException ex) {
        return "fail " + ex.getMessage();
    }

}
```

My spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">


<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none" />

<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/accessdenied" access="permitAll" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

    <form-login />

    <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />


    <!-- <session-management invalid-session-url="/loginlimmit">
        <concurrency-control error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"
            max-sessions="1" />
    </session-management> -->

</http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>

        <user-service>
            <user name="a" password="a" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>

    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

This works fine

1 - if I try to access http: //localhost/app is redirect to http: //localhost/app/spring_security_login to login as expected

2 - if I send POST method to http: //localhost/app/login works, I receive the message sucess or fail as expected using credentials username=a and password=a as defined in Spring-security.xml in authentication provider, so it really authenticate using spring .security.

**The problems**

After send POST method and get login sucess, if I try to acess http: //localhost/app is redirect to http: //localhost/app/spring_security_login , so I cant undestand beacause the authentication worked fine!

How can get User authenticated in others controllers?

My goals is develop an application with Spring MVC but I will not use as standard web application, it will works like Backend application and the frontend will be other application, such as desktop, mobile, vaadin framework and these application will comunicate using JSON, the Spring MVC works fine to  this, but I need to implement the authentication, in this case, using Spring Security.

any hep?

Comment: Why? Spring Security already does all that (and more) why are you working against/around instead of with the framework?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to setup a controller, Spring Security has a chain of filters it uses to authenticate, you just need to post your username/password to that chain.

```
<form-login 
    password-parameter="password" --> password field
    username-parameter="username" --> username field
    login-processing-url="/security/j_spring_security_check"  --> set your form's action attribute to this URL, no need to implement anything at that URL
    login-page="/login" --> login page 
/>
```

Comment: there is no form attribute in a desktop or moble application

Comment: @KJEjava48 you do a `POST` to `/security/j_spring_security_check` with `username` and `password` parameters.

Comment: the restTemplate allow me to use POST with only one parameter.So i need to pass this username and password using a Mulivaluemap or a json object.Then how spring security will split this username and password from the map or json???

Comment: @KJEjava48, your question is how to use rest template, I suggest you google that.

Comment: no.I am asking you how this spring security will identify the username and password from json object from the post request

Comment: @KJEjava48 what are you talking about? What JSON object? There is no JSON object, there is username and password parameters, that's all. Learn the basics of HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

```
1 - if I try to access http: //localhost/app is redirect to http: //localhost/app/spring_security_login to login as expected
```

If the normal way of login works and its not redirecting to login page again when you request the `http: //localhost/app` then your configuration is good.

```
After send POST method and get login sucess, if I try to acess http: //localhost/app is redirect to http: //localhost/app/spring_security_login , so I cant undestand beacause the authentication worked fine!
```

For each request , the application considers as new session. if you have configured Spring Security filter already in web.xml ( which makes the point 1 works fine) should create Session for you, So you can just call `getSession()` instead of `getSession(true)` in your controller.

Just log the session id between the request and see the sessions are different. it may be due to the way you are calling from client.

Comment: can you provide any example how to avoid create new session from the controller? I have change the code of the controller but it didnt work.

Comment: Ok , For each request you are getting different session ?

Comment: Exacly, how can I avoid this?

Comment: You have to handle this in your client. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159848/maintaining-http-session-when-accessing-a-servlet-from-android